# How will I write these bash commands in python

Tags: bash, shell-script, python3

I need to write sed, cat in python

```
ID_PSEXEC1="hello"
type4="test"

sed "s/^/$ID_PSEXEC1,/" psexec.csv > temp && mv temp psexec.csv
cat psexec.csv > psexec_1.csv
sed "s/^/$type4,/" psexec_1.csv > temp && mv temp psexec_1.csv


cat psexec_1.csv > PsEXEC_Execution.csv
```

Comment: I voted to close as too broad because I'm not sure this question would be well received on SO either.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Regardless where you post this question, you need to show that you've attempted to solve it first, then the community will help you with the more specific issues.

Comment: Read up in the regex library, and reading and writing files. Or are you wishing to call helper programs (as bash does)?

Answer (score 1):

The Software Architecture Group (SWAG) has created `bash2py`. According to https://www.swag.uwaterloo.ca/bash2py/index.html:

> > Bash2py is a Bash to Python script translator [...]

Install that and put your bash script through it.
Haven't tried it, so I'm not really sure about the quality of the outputted script.